# trouble with left aligned text positioned on the right of the page?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, text, text-alignment

I'm having trouble on Wordpress; I'm trying to float an excerpt text box to the right hand side of the page whilst still keeping it left aligned. I've tried aligning the PHP to the right which put the position right but also aligns from the right. I'm not sure about linking the CSS with only the excerpts PHP.

This is the PHP above & CSS below

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content">
 <div id="entry_content">
 <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

 <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

  <?php if(is_home()) { if ( function_exists('wp_list_comments') ) { ?>  <div <?php   post_class(); ?>> <?php }} ?>

 <!--<h2 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"      title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
      <p class="date"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> <?php comments_popup_link('&sect; <span class="commentcount">0 comments</span>', '&sect; <span class="commentcount">1 comment</span>', '&sect; <span class="commentcount">% comments</span>'); ?></p>-->

       <div class="post">

 <?php { if ( function_exists('add_theme_support')) the_post_thumbnail( 'post-thumbnail' ); } ?>      

 <?php the_content('&raquo; Read the rest of this entry &laquo;'); ?>  
    <div class="pagination">
      <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<p><span>Page</span>', 'after' => '</p>',       'next_or_number' => 'number')); ?>
    </div>

 </p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p></a></div>
  </div>

    <p class="tags"><?php the_tags('<span>Tagged </span> ', ', ', ''); ?></p>

  <?php endwhile; ?>

  <div class="navigation">
    <p class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></p>
        <p class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></p>
  </div>

   <?php else : ?>

  <div class="entry">
   <span class="error"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?      >/images/mal.png"       alt="error duck" /></span>
    <p>Hmmm, seems like what you were looking for isn't here.  You might want to give      it   another try - the server might have hiccuped - or maybe you even spelled something wrong (though it's more likely <strong>I</strong> did).</p>
   </div>

<?php endif; ?>

</div> <!-- close entry_content -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

CSS:

```
/* =Layout
------------------------------------------------------------------*/
 #wrapper {
width: 75em;
margin: 0 ;
 }

 #header {
  display: block;
 }

 #main_nav {
width: 0em;
margin: -1.8em 0 0 0;
float: left;
display: inline;
    position: fixed;
    width: 120px;
height: 100%;
    padding: 0em 0em 0em 3em;
background: #f5f5f5
 }

 {TO POSITION THE PAGE TEMPLATE CHANGE WIDTH & MARGIN=HEIGHT}

 #content {
width: 55em;
margin: 1em 0 0 0;
float: right;
display: inline;
min-height: 30em;
 }

  #post_content {
width: 100em;
margin: 10em 2.5em 0 1.5em;
float: left;
display: inline;
  }

  {TO POSITION THE POSTS TEMPLATE CHANGE WIDTH & MARGIN=HEIGHT}

 .post {
    width: 83em;
margin: 1.5em 0 0 0;
float: right;
display: inline;
min-height: 30em;
 }
```

Comment: You do know that you can't "align PHP" with CSS right?  PHP helps you generate the proper HTML, which is then styled with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #content {
width: 55em;
margin: 1em 0 0 0;
float: right;
display: inline;
min-height: 30em;
text-align:left;
 }
```

Comment: sorry, i wasnt sure if it was possible to align anything using only php. that doesn't seem to change anything, its still aligned from the left but at the left hand side of the screen  . Is there css styles i could use with a div tag around the php excerpt text?

Comment: check your html around this:  </p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p></a></div>
  </div>